# Why does Mongoose throws ValidationError when running test in CI although the type declaration is OK?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting this error: `ValidationError: MySchema validation failed: name: Cast to String failed for value "some-string" (type string) at path "name" because of "TypeError"` while running my unit tests in GitHub Actions (The test tries to insert a new MySchema document before the test). Obviously, that's weird since it gets a string for casting so I really can't see why it doesn't work...

Schema is along:

```
var MySchema = {
  ...
  name: { type: String, get: encryption.decrypt, set: encryption.encrypt },
  ...
}
```

And the test util is along:

```
const generateMySchema = ({ name, ... }) => {
  const name = `test_myschema_${Date.now()}`;
  let myTestSchema = new MySchema({
    name,
    ...
  });
  return myTestSchema;
};
```

This does not reproduce locally nor there's this problem in our testing/production environments.

I've tried many things, like adding the `{ typeKey: '$type' }` but it's not what I really want, since my key should be [automatically](https://I%27m%20getting%20this%20error:%20%60ValidationError:%20%3CMySchema%3E%20validation%20failed:%20name:%20Cast%20to%20String%20failed%20for%20value%20%22some-string%22%20(type%20string)%20at%20path%20%22name%22%20because%20of%20%22TypeError%22%60%20while%20running%20my%20unit%20tests%20in%20GitHub%20Actions.%20Obviously,%20that%27s%20weird%20since%20it%20gets%20a%20string%20for%20casting%20so%20I%20really%20can%27t%20see%20why%20it%20doesn%27t%20work...%20Schema%20is%20along:%20%60%60%60%20var%20MySchema%20=%20%7B%20%20%20...%20%20%20name:%20%7B%20type:%20String,%20get:%20encryption.decrypt,%20set:%20encryption.encrypt%20%7D,%20%20%20...%20%7D%20%60%60%60%20This%20does%20not%20reproduce%20locally%20nor%20there%27s%20this%20problem%20in%20our%20testing/production%20environments.%20%20I%27ve%20tried%20many%20things,%20like%20adding%20the%20%60%7B%20typeKey:%20%27$type%27%20%7D%60%20but%20it%27s%20not%20what%20I%20really%20want,%20since%20my%20key%20should%20be%20automatically%20used%20for%20type.%20I%27ve%20worked%20around%20this%20by%20using:%20%60%60%60%20var%20validateBeforeSave%20=%20process.env.NODEJS_ENV%20!==%20%22test-ci%22;%20MySchema.set(%22validateBeforeSave%22,%20validateBeforeSave);%20%60%60%60%20But%20then%20I%20miss%20this%20functionality%20in%20our%20tests.%20%20Mongoose%20version:%206.10.1%20Mongo%20version:%205.0.6%20%20Thanks%20for%20any%20help!) used for type.
I've worked around this by using:

```
var validateBeforeSave = process.env.NODEJS_ENV !== "test-ci";
MySchema.set("validateBeforeSave", validateBeforeSave);
```

But then I miss this functionality in our tests.

Mongoose version: 6.10.1
Mongo version: 5.0.6

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Its very odd because `Cast to String failed for value "some-string" (type string)` is a bit of a paradox. What version of Node is your GitHub Actions running? There was a big push last year to migrate users onto V16 from v12 and v10 in some cases. Just a hunch...

Comment: @JQueeny Yes, we've too upgraded some year ago to Node V18 and our Actions run on actions/setup-node@v3 Node 18.14.2. Locally(Mac) with the same versions it works... Thanks for the hunch anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, with removing `get: encryption.decrypt, set: encryption.encrypt` the error disappeared.

These getter and setter use `crypto` npm package for encryption and they still return a string, **but** they work using an environment variable that was missing for the encryption. They probably returned an object of some sort.

Adding the environment variable as a secret in the repository and use it:

1. Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions > New repository secret.
2. Then in the workflow under `env:`: `ENCRYPTION_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ENCRYPTION_SECRET }}`

Solved it.
Hope it might help anyone...